# A word that means the study of the human in relation to the animal and vice versa

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests, philosophy

I am looking for a word/adjective that can fit to describe the human and the animal in relation to each other. A word like 'zoology'does not quite work, because it means the study of animals independent of humans. 'Ecology' hardly works either; it does not convey exactly what stated.

What I need is an adjective whose meaning gives the effect of something like **the 'human-animal'relationship**, especially how each stands in relation to the other in nature.

> Examples:
>
> *Gulliver's Travels* has redefined the human-animal relationship
>
> *Gulliver's Travels* has redefined the position of the human in
> relation to the animal.

Comment: **Interspecies** relationship.

Comment: @JoeDark- That just sounds icky.

Answer (score 2):

***Anthrozoology***

> Anthrozoology (also known as human–non-human-animal studies, or HAS) is the study of interaction between humans and other animals.
>
> A major focus of anthrozoologic research is the quantifying of the positive effects of human-animal relationships on either party and the study of their interactions.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthrozoology

---

<sub>*Anthro-* is from comb. form of Greek *anthropos* "man, human being". 

*Zoo-*  from comb. form of Greek *zoion* "an animal".</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between *sentient* and *non-sentient* animals.